# Is an application's name available as a variable?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

When I create a rails application,

**console:**

```
rails new foo
```

Is the string "foo" available to my code?

```
puts "Your app's name is " + app_name_bar
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`Rails.application.class` will get you the full name of the application (eg. YourAppName::Application).

From there you can get the module name with `Rails.application.class.parent`.

Comment: `Rails.application.class.parent.to_s.underscore` for the actual naming

Answer (score 1):

In rails 6 you need to change from `Rails.application.class.parent` to `Rails.application.class.module_parent`